# Shiny Javascript Events not working with $(#id) jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

In the documentation from RStudio about javascripts events in shiny https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/js-events.html, there is this example for the `shiny:value` event :

```
$('#foo').on('shiny:value', function(event) {
  // append a character string to the output value
  event.value += ' Oh that is nice!';
});

// use event.target to obtain the output element
$(document).on('shiny:value', function(event) {
  // cancel the output of the element with id 'foo'
  if (event.target.id === 'foo') {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

and it says :

> Since these events are triggered specifically on an output element,
> you may add the listener on the output element instead of on the
> document, although the latter also works, e.g.

but when I try to use the first method in my shiny app, it doesn't seems to work.

For example if you run the app bellow, only the method with the `$(document)` selector is working and triggers a message.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(
      "$('#my_table').on('shiny:value', function(event) {
        alert('MSG 1');
      });"
    ), 
    tags$script(
      "$(document).on('shiny:value', function(event) {
        if (event.target.id === 'my_table') {
          alert('MSG 2');
        }
      });"
    )
  ),
  
  sliderInput("my_slider", "Rows", 1, 20, 1),
  tableOutput("my_table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$my_table <- renderTable(iris[1:input$my_slider, ])
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I suppose that I'm missing something as in the documentation, it says that the 2 method should work. Any help appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the table does not exist (is not in the DOM) yet when the script is read. You can do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#my_table').on('shiny:value', function(event) {
    alert('MSG 1');
  });
});
```

Another way that should work is to put the script at the end of the UI, without `tags$head`.